# can i create instaces using jenkins in openstack

Tags: jenkins, openstack

I am working on college project. which includes technologies Jenkins and open stack.
I want to automate creating multiply instances in Open stack using Jenkins  but I'm looking for a plug in that will allow me to create instances in Open stack without going to the site and login in. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

There's no plugin for Jenkins that I'm aware of to create servers in an Openstack site.

You can create some simple python scripts using the openstacksdk to do what you need. It's found here: https://github.com/openstack/python-openstacksdk  Then you just use the 'Execute shell' build step in Jenkins to run the python scripts.

One hint to help you get started, newer releases of Openstack will need you to pass project_domain_name and user_domain_name info in the args of Connection.  This is unfortunately not in the documentation.  Look at python-openstacksdk/examples/compute/create.py for the specifics of creating a server(vm) in your site.